# Redirect form to different URLs based on option selection

Tags: html, jquery

I want to redirect a form to different URLs based on option selection.
However, it will redirect the user to the URL without the click submit button.

How can I fix this?

```
<form action="#">
<select id="selectbox" name="" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
    <option value="https://www.google.com/" selected>Option1</option>
    <option value="https://www.maybank.com/">Option2</option>
    <option value="https://www.gmail.com/">Option3</option>

</select>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

jquery

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#selectbox").change(function () {
        location.href = jQuery(this).val();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **submit** method from jquery, you can use something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("form").submit(function(){
  location.href = $('#selectbox').val();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
 <select id="selectbox" name="">
     <option value="https://www.google.com/" selected>Option1</option>
     <option value="https://www.maybank.com/">Option2</option>
     <option value="https://www.gmail.com/">Option3</option>
 </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: hi, i try it at codepen https://codepen.io/wanted88/pen/YzyRXaa but i got "Bad Path" error

Comment: please dont use codepen for something like form submission or redirecting, take time to create new local file. thannk you.: :)

Comment: I also implement in my code, but the url change to `http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/addstory.html?select=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F#`   when i submit the form

Comment: or maybe you need event.preventDefault() here's the code https://pastebin.com/mChtYdKA

Comment: thank you, I tried but still not working. Here is  the full code  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wanted88/87yqg1k5/18/)

Comment: `$("#addstory")` you should put the `#` on the selector :)